# Zend Studio 9 trial, i can't find the SVN perspective

Tags: svn, zend-studio

I recently installed Zend Studio 9 for windows trial version.
In order to check out a project from SVN i'm supposed to open the SVN perspective to add a repository location.
My problem is that i can't find the SVN perspective by any means. the documentation says:
"*Open the SVN perspective by going to **Window** | **Open Perspective** | **Other** | **SVN Repository Exploring***".but actually there is no **SVN Repository Exploring**.

anyone can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also looking for the SVN Repositories in Zend Studio 9.0
After some searching i found a way for me.

In the PHP Explorer just try to add create a new project on File > New > Project for SVN.

I may case Zend Studio asked me if i wanted the SVN feature and it installed the software

Comment: thanks, worked fine with me.
but i wonder why should i walk through this? why it is not enabled by default?

Comment: We preferred to make Zend Studio leaner and faster by removing some parts of it. But on the other hand we made it very easy to install and discover new plugins on top of it. See http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/zend-studio.htm

Comment: Where is the log View, I can't see where is the svn log printed (which file is updated, etc...)